# Is there a way to avoid blocking when calling lua_resume?

Tags: c, lua, luajit

I need some help trying to understand the following scenario as my current knowledge on the matter is insufficient and I’m not sure where to start.

From a C pthread that has a main Lua state, each request creates a Lua coroutine, puts a pre-registered Lua function and some arg on the stack and starts it with lua_resume. This Lua script function does a io.popen and calls a C function that takes the FILE* from the io.popen, gets the corresponding fd, sets it to non-blocking adds it to a read event q ueue and does lua_yield. So far so good, C takes over. When C calls back lua_resume, it blocks until I finish reading all content from the fd associated with the FILE* in question. Is there any way I can avoid that blocking? What if I only want to read one char and go back to C immediately not caring about the remaining output from io.popen?

I tried this in both LuaJIT 2.1beta3 and Lua 5.1 and they behave the same.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend very much on the C code, not the Lua code? Lua code has no concept of "blocking"; it's whatever code `lua_resume` called that does the blocking.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I meant to say "unless I finish reading" instead of "until I finish reading". I can edit if necessary. Basically if I keep reading from the fd in a non-blocking fashion I can get control to go back and forth between C and Lua, but if I want to only get one character and call lua_resume, it blocks until io.popen appears to finish its process.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I would agree with that and that's part of why it's beyond me. First lua_resume starts the coroutine for the main Lua function (from C), then second lua_resume tries to resume that main Lua function (from C) after it's called from Lua. It might sound a bit confusing, let me know if I should write some code.

Comment: I think I found the blocking code. In the Lua script, calling the corresponding f:close() of the f = io.popen(..) blocks the continuation of the Lua script until the process finishes. Will the GC collect it if I don't explicitly close it (to avoid blocking)?

Comment: @humand - Pipes are limited OS resource, you should close them manually after use.  Of course, Lua could do it for you, but then the blocking would happen inside GC :-)  Will `f:close()` block or not - depends on OS.  Lua just calls a C library function.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff Thank you both for the clues to understand this, greatly appreciated!